# Inheriting base class events

Tags: c#, inheritance, event-handling, derived-class, base-class

I do not know if there is an answer to this - I can not seem to find examples so maybe my terminology is not right or maybe this should not be done so forgive me for asking.

I have a base class with an object that has several events and event handling code - basically this is a boiler plate process using a FileSystemWatcher.

In my base I have all the code wired up for handling particular events and error handling.

The issue is that I am looking to be able to control what events of file system watcher the base class should subscribe to (was thinking to include all and use a switch case to add them)  but then I need to handle them in the derived class and not in the base - because there is specific functionality of the derived classes that I want. I do not want to implement all the events in the base if possible - because I do not want the overhead when 4 to 8 of these derived classes are running. One thing I would like is force a derived class to SUBSCRIBE to an event.

I know from DCcoder that abstract was key in forcing methods to be 'must inherit' but I am at a loss on forcing the subscription.

```
    public abstract class myBase
    {

        public event EventHandler<string> MessageAvailable;

        protected void OnMessageAvailable(string e)
        {
             MessageAvailable?.Invoke(this, e);

        }


       public event EventHandler<Exception> Error;

        protected virtual void OnError(Exception e)
        {
            Error?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

    }


public myderivedclass : myBase
{

      this.Message += IfYouwantTo;
      this.Error += REQUIRE_THIS_SUBSCRIPTION_HandleErrorHere;

}
```

DerivedClass needs to actually handle the events so do I create an empty event handler in the base class and use an interface to force my derived class to override the base  or rather than that force the derived class to implement the handler ??

Or am I going about this all wrong ?

Any examples are appreciated ..

Comment: The code you provided is not a valid C# code sample. Please provide a [mcve] (**minimal** and **complete** are important).

Comment: Why can't you use an abstract base class with abstract methods for those that have a specific functionality?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are going for here. It almost sounds like you could just do everything in the derived classes. Please clarify or show a more complete example

Comment: @DCCoder I have not used abstract classes and my understanding is limited. So I will do some searching on that for the moment.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET the process is a boiler plate for the most part - so all of the error handling and event management is basically the same with the exception of this particular event functionality , so I would like to simply have one base class with the workings for the boiler plate, and the derived class handle specifics. I think I am going to pass in an object and switch on it in the base, and bubble up an event to be handled by the derived class. ??

Comment: @DCCoder I ended up making the base class abstract. and added the abstract method.  I have one event that I need all derives to subscribe to ; Is there anyway I can force a subscription to an event ?

Comment: If you could update your question to show the code that you are currently working with we would be able to help you a lot more.

Comment: @DCCoder I updated with a brief example and I did follow your previous advice abstract base class and methods- only one issue - is force  a particular subscription , the handler I declared abstract. but would I declare the event abstract ?? to force the subscription ??

Comment: Ok, so basically you have an event in the base class, and you want the derived classes to handle the event differently but you want to ensure that they are implementing a handler.

Is that correct?

Comment: @DCCoder I have the handler method as abstract - so they must include that for sure, but abstract handler does not force the subscription to the event - I might be doing overkill here but I want to make sure if someone is using the code that they not only put code in the handler but also subscribe to the event.- they should know to do this .. and maybe I am on overkill.

Comment: See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857159/enforcing-implementation-of-events-in-derived-abstract-classes  

That should be what you're looking for

Comment: @DCCoder I can raise the event from the base that is occurring and the handler is forced by being declared abstract - but I have subscribed to it because I know to do so - because the method is there an implementation is done. (like in VS the implementation will automagically be there) the one thing that will not be there is this.MyEvent += MyAbstractHandler_I_forced_you_to write_some _kind_of_code_for.  Maybe I am over thinking this and should just say anyone using my code should know they need to do that??